# how to cast Edm.Guid to Edm.String in odata

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api

how to cast guid into string in odata, i have tried the `$filter=(startswith(cast(CustomerID, 'Edm.String'),'1'))` but it throws exception Unknown function 'cast'.

Comment: OData v4 support that.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? On the one hand, a Guid isn't supposed to have any business meaning. On the other, you could use a range query and avoid a cast that prevents the query from using indexes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, want to perform filtering action based on the guid value, how to use range query

Answer (score 2):

To perform a cast, the type shouldn't be in quotes. So it should be:

```
$filter=startswith(cast(CustomerID, Edm.String),'1')
```

(I also removed the extra brackets)